# How do I return 60 sets of month and year data in a month and year column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am provided two variables, `@month` and `@year` of integer type (therefore month is 1, 2, 3, ... 9, 10, 11, 12 and year is the four-digit year).

What I am looking to do is create a table valued function that will take in these two parameters and return the past 60 months, and then year ends to 2005.

So, for example, with `@month = 1` and `@year = 2018`, I am looking to return this table:

```
+----+------+
| 1  | 2018 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 11 | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 10 | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 9  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 8  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 7  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2017 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 11 | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 10 | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 9  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 8  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 7  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2016 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 11 | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 10 | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 9  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 8  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 7  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2015 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 11 | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 10 | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 9  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 8  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 7  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2014 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 11 | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 10 | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 9  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 8  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 7  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 6  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2013 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2012 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2011 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2010 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2009 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2008 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2007 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2006 |
+----+------+
| 12 | 2005 |
+----+------+
```

I was thinking of doing this several ways, with a cross-join perhaps, or some while loop - but they seem really inefficient. I don't think it's the most difficult to do, but I want to write 'good' code for it. I have been pondering over the "best" way for quite some time now.

Unfortunately, I don't have any say in how the data comes to me and this is the return I need to give, otherwise I'd be using date datatypes and date functions.

Comment: Best is always subjective. I'm sure someone will post a great CTE or a dimension table that makes it a simple select with a union or a simple cross join. What makes you think a loop's performance would be a problem? My bet is they would basically be identical and inconsistent between runs.

Comment: I think it's simply a matter of having been told to completely avoid cursors or looping.

Comment: For large in-memory operations, that is true, but this seems quite small. Make you a deal. You show me your looping solution and I'll provide a non-looping solution. :)

Comment: I would absolutely solve this with a loop(s).  Any performance hit will be minimal compared to the amount of time spent trying to come up with a "better" solution.   "Completely avoid loops" is something you tell beginners before they're ready to understand why they should be avoided, and when they needn't be.

Comment: That's a good point, it's rather funny though, in our coding standards at my office there's one line referring to cursors that simply says 'CURSORS - Should be avoided' and that's all. A little humor for you all I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be to persist this in a table.  Basically, create a table going as far back as necessary, and then have it go into the future some 50 years.  Then, your function can just select from that table.

table:

```
create table MonthDim
(
PK_ID int identity(1, 1) primary key,
Month int,
Year int,
Dt date --set this to the first of each month
)
```

query:

```
select *
from MonthDim
where dt >= dateadd(month, -60, datefromparts(@year, @month, 1))
    and dt <= datefromparts(@year, @month, 1)

union all

select *
from MonthDim
where dt < dateadd(month, -60, datefromparts(@year, @month, 1))
    and Month = 12
```

The added benefit of this is that, since it's persisted, should you need to save any data generated down stream you can reference the primary key here.  It's also just easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Your query would not produce the desired results:  "...and year ends to 2005".   But I do agree with the strategy of persisting a table, if the business allows it.

Comment: It's funny that you mention the persisting of a table because for spending WAY too much time trying to come up with an optimal solution I found that we do that a persisted table of month/years. This is a great solution, as I was unaware of `datefromparts` and that hadn't come up in my searching.

Answer (score 2):

This uses recursive CTEs. Naturally I'd just use a [dimension table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) if your environment allows for it. This is **a way** but the **best way** is arguable, of course.

```
declare @year int = 2018
declare @month int = 1



;with cte as(
    select [Month], [Year] = 2005
    from  (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) as X([Month]) 
    union all
    select [Month], [Year] + 1
    from cte
    where [Year] < @year
),

someYears as(
select [Years] = 2005
union all
select [Years] + 1
from someYears
where [Years] < @year),

t as(
select  *, RN = row_number() over (order by [Year] desc, [Month] desc) 
from cte
where [Month] <= case when [Year] = @year then @month else 13 end)


select [Month], [Year]
from t
where RN <= 60
union 
select 12, [Years]
from (select [Years] from someYears) x
where x.Years < @year
order by [Year] desc, [Month] desc
```

Comment: Read OP's second paragraph again.   He probably should have put a comma after "months".

Comment: Thank you for your time. Interestingly, I stumbled upon a persisted table deep within the depths. I hadn't heard the phrase dimension table, but that looks like what we're dealing with. I truly thank you for your time and effort I have learned some new things.

Comment: No worries @Soulfire, wish yall would have beat Villanova :(

Comment: Same! But the run was magical nonetheless :). Thanks for everything!